# Why does my table stay blank even though it echos Success?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Hello there I've written some PHP that gets XML from a website, and will store it on a table on my database. It echo's Success, yet the table is blank? Heres my code:

```
<?php

$url ="http://rates.fxcm.com/RatesXML3";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password"); //this does contain proper information, just ive hidden it with the following
mysql_select_db("database", $con) or die(mysql_error()); //same for database too

foreach ($xml -> Rate as $row){
    $Symbol = $row -> Symbol;
    $Bid = $row -> Bid;
    $Ask = $row -> Ask;

//performing sql query

$sql = "INSERT INTO 'FXCM_Rates' ('Symbol', 'Bid', 'Ask')"  
            . "VALUES ('$Symbol', '$Bid', '$Ask')";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!result) {
    echo 'MySQL ERROR';
    } else{
    echo 'SUCCESS';
}
}
```

?>

Now when I check the PHP, it has echoed success for all 63 Rates, yet when I go to check the table, it is blank? I just find it odd that it has worked for everyone else, but not me :(

Thanks to anyone that can help fix my code / point out my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have '$' missing in the end.

```
  if (!$result) {
```

Also now that I've done some tests, your variables are objects which I'm not sure that you can INSERT in database like that.

```
foreach ($xml -> Rate as $row){
 $Symbol = (string)$row -> Symbol;
 $Bid    = (string)$row -> Bid;
 $Ask    = (string)$row -> Ask;
}
```

This will return strings that might be easier to use for you query

Comment: okay that worked, but now im getting MySQL errors xD. I guess it pointed out why it was "Working" but not returning a result though, so its time to work out why it isnt working. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

mysql is deprecated in newer version of php, you should be using mysqli(improved)..

```
<?php

$url ="http://rates.fxcm.com/RatesXML3";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database") or die(mysqli_error($con));

foreach ($xml -> Rate as $row){
    $Symbol = $row -> Symbol;
    $Bid = $row -> Bid;
    $Ask = $row -> Ask;

//performing sql query

$sql = "INSERT INTO 'FXCM_Rates' ('Symbol', 'Bid', 'Ask')"  
            . "VALUES ('$Symbol', '$Bid', '$Ask')";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo 'MySQL ERROR';
    } else{
    echo 'SUCCESS';
}
}
```